# htaccess redirect to base URL if URL contains parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect all url's that contain the parameter `?lang=` to my base url.

For example: If `www.example.com/?lang=ru` redirect to `www.example.com`.

I have tried with RedirectMatch but it's not working.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Redirect*` directives do not handle the query string so you need to use URL rewriting instead.

```
RewriteEngine on

# if the query string contains a parameter called "lang"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=
# then redirect (permanently) to /
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expressions

If you want to use a Regular Expression to redirect something, use the RedirectMatchdirective:

RedirectMatch "^/lang=ru?.html/?$" "http://example.com/newfile.php"

Don't forget have mod_rewrite on in your apache configuration, and other configuration neccessary for enable your htaccess file.